# Prevent adding duplicate data into JTable in Java(jtable)

Tags: java, jtable

This is a jtable code that receives data in order when you click the insert button. What should I do if I get a duplicate value when I receive a value of txtMovie and get an alert message?
this is my code..

```
private void btnInsertActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt{
                                      
    int iCntRow=0;
    int iOrder=0;
    int iGallery=0;
    
    iCntRow=jTable1.getRowCount();
    for(int idx=0;idx<jTable1.getRowCount();idx++){
        if(jTable1.getValueAt(idx,0)==null){
            iCntRow=idx;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    iOrder=Integer.parseInt(txtOrder.getText());
    jTable1.setValueAt(iOrder, iCntRow, 0);
    
    
    
    jTable1.setValueAt(txtMovie.getText(), iCntRow, 1);

    iGallery=Integer.parseInt(txtGallery.getText());
    jTable1.setValueAt(iGallery, iCntRow, 2);
    
    
}
```

Comment: I will try to give answers on the basis of the question which I understand. 

I assume you don't want an insert duplicate movie value on JTable which got from the txtMovie field, then you can use some approach before sets value on JTable such as

Used Set collection to get unique value or read JTable to check if the value is present on the table.